# Create Signature for Flickr Authentication (Android SDK)

Tags: android, oauth, flickr, signature

I want to upload pictures to Flickr with my little Android-App. So the user have to log in and accept the permissions.

My problem is, that I don't know what the parameters are to create the signature.
This is written on the Flickr Website:

> The base string is constructed by concatenating the HTTP verb, the request URL, and all request parameters sorted by name, using lexicograhpical byte value ordering, separated by an '&'.

What are the "request parameters"? 
I've tried it several times with different parameters, but got always that error: "Invalid api key or signature".

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lets break it down.

You need to start with the HTTP verb. Lets say that you are doing a GET request. Part 1 of the signature base string is:

`GET`

Then lets say you are calling the URL http://www.example.com/api/?filename=hello.jpg. Ignore the parameter and you have part 2:

`http://www.example.com/api/`

Then lets say you have the following parameters, `filename` is from the URL above. The ones prepended with `oauth_` are needed for the request to be allowed by the server.

- oauth_consumer_key=9djdj82h48djs9d2,
- oauth_token=kkk9d7dh3k39sjv7,
- oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1
- oauth_timestamp=137131201
- oauth_nonce=7d8f3e4a
- filename=hello.jpg

All of the parameters above need to be sorted in lexicographical byte value order (basically alphabetically), separated by an '&'. Now you will have the third part part:

`filename=hello.jpg&oauth_consumer_key=9djdj82h48djs9d2&
oauth_nonce=7d8f3e4a&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=
137131201&oauth_token=kkk9d7dh3k39sjv7`

Now you need to URL encode part 2 and part 3. Then concatenate the three parts, resulting in:

`GET&http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fapi%2F&filename%3Dhello.jpg%26oauth_consumer_key%3D9djdj82h48djs9d2%26%0Aoauth_nonce%3D7d8f3e4a%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D%0A137131201%26oauth_token%3Dkkk9d7dh3k39sjv7`

This is the base string. Now you need to sign it using the HMAC-SHA1 algorithm, the resulting signature has to be sent with the request as well.

Comment: Wow, great! Thank you so so much. But what is the oauth_nonce and where did I get the timestamp?

Comment: Nonce is a random string, unique for every request, you have to generate it yourself. It stands for "number used only once", but can be any combination of letters or numbers. The timestamp is simply the current GMT time, expressed as a unix timestamp. Both these parameters make sure that any individual request cannot be "replayed" maliciously. Every request has to be signed with new nonce and timestamp.

Comment: After getting the request_token I ran into the next problem. I need the oauth_verifier to exchange the request token for the access token. The Flickr page says that I should use this call: `http://www.flickr.com/services/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=72157626737672178-022bbd2f4c2f3432` and that the return value should include this verifier. But the Java lib only offers methods for getting the two tokens and I'm uncertain how to call the posted url to get the verifier.

Comment: The /authorize URL you mention is to be opened in a browser. It will contain a login dialogue that an end user must fill in. Once completed it redirects to a callback URL that you have either registered with your application or supplied as oauth_callback parameter in the request token request. That callback URL should be a URL that you control so that you can intercept the oauth_verifier that gets sent to it. Once you have the verifier you can do the final step in the OAuth dance. Getting the access token.

Comment: Since you are on android. You can probably use an app URL as callback. Try. Or read Flickr's docs.

Comment: One of the clear and perfect answer I saw in Stackoverflow! This helped me a lot. Thanks Jon. :)

Comment: OMG! I was getting crazy with this procedure. Thanks a lot for the step by step! I really doubt that's clear enough in the Flickr API docs.